# what does this statement do in C?

Tags: c

Can you explain to me what does this statement `x^=y` do in C ?
I already know that the caret character mean XOR but putting the caret before the equal sign confused me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about simple syntax.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - Simple syntax is not relevant to programmers?

Comment: I'm really not sure how this question is __too broad__.

Comment: why I am getting so much downvotes , is it because its a stupid question ?

Comment: @user3791563, downvote not from me, but yes the answer to this question can probably be found by looking for the basics about C, e.g "C operators" or something like that. SO is not meant to replace a simple search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shortcut operation, just like

```
x += 1; // same as x = x + 1
x ^= y; // same as x = x ^ y
```

Answer (score 3):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator. The expression `x ^= y` means that the program will compute `x ^ y` and then set `x` to that value.

Answer (score 2):

`x ^= y` is the same as `x = x ^ y` with the condition that `x` is only evaluated once.

The complete list of these operators include:

```
x *= y
x /= y
x %= y
x += y
x -= y
x <<= y
x >>= y
x &= y
x ^= y
x |= y
```

Answer (score 1):

`^=` is a compound assignment operator.

```
x^=y
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x ^ y
```

but `x` being evaluated only once.